# Translate LINQ Inline query to extension method

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, join, extension-methods

I can't seem to figure out the LINQ Join extension method... I have the following LINQ inline query:

```
var cc = from z in zipcodes
         join c in contactsRepo.UDF_SelectSome() on z.Zipcode equals c.Zip
```

What is the equivalent of this in LINQ-extension-method syntax?

Comment: Your question, and all questions of this form, are answered in section 7.16 of the C# specification.

Comment: And if you don't want to read the spec, tools like ReSharper happily convert back and forth for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean Lambda syntax?

```
var cc = zipcodes.Join(contactsRepo.UDF_SelectSome(),
                       z => z.Zipcode,
                       c => c.Zip,
                       (z, c) => c);
```

Comment: If I want the (z, c) => new to be of type contactsRepoResults, do I still need to cast it, or can I just do something like new contactsRepoResults() ? Because essentially I'm using the join only as a filter, I still want the same stuff returned that would usually be returned by contactsRepo.UDF_SelectSome().

Comment: @Alex - I updated to reflect that. Keep in mind, though, that your original post won't give you those results. It will return a new anonymous type with the combined fields of the two tables unless you specify a select clause.

Comment: I shortened my original post because my main issue was the join. In your update, you show FieldOne = z.FieldOne etc. - is it possible to automagically assign it a type without casting each field? Because my type has 30+ fields, and I really don't need any field from the zipcode table, so it's the same fields that would ordinarily be returned by the UDF (and then casted correctly)

Comment: Alternatively, can I have the join return an IQueryable?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the join to filter, and you want just the object from one set, use the selector (last parameter) that picks that object.

```
var cc = contactsRepo.UDF_SelectSome().Join(
  zipcodes,
  c => c.Zip,
  z => z.Zipcode,
  (c, z) => c);
```

Or, if you just want to filter:

```
var cc = contactsRepo.UDF_SelectSome()
  .Where(c => zipcodes.Any(z => c.Zip == z.ZipCode))
```

Comment: The (c, z) => c was exactly what I was looking for.